# Interactive Graph display using TA-Lib

Tags: .net

I am looking after an interactive and tick-by-tick graphical software using TA-Lib to run in .NET where I can used my own datafeed (forex prices). Recommendations are welcome.

Rgds

Answer (score 0):

http://openforexplatform.com will do the trick.

TA-Lib is integrated into the platform to provide the indicators, however you may need to do a bit of coding in order to get tick-by-tick implemented, as I think the lowest timeframe supported is 1m.

The platform is extremely well written and if you know C# you can implement whatever datasources you have access to with relative ease.